# Running an executable script using different time and date using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running a script using the `command` method in `os` package in python using the following code:

```
import os
os.command(c:\crypt\maze.exe)
```

I wish to run an executable script using different time and date than that of computer's clock. Can somebody guide me towards that end?

Comment: Do you have the source code of the executable and can modify it? supply a datetime - delta on startup and add/Subtract in the program from the computer clock. Or explain what you want to achieve with that.

Comment: Take a look at python scheduler. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule

Comment: @PatrickArtner No, i don't have the executable file for the script.

Comment: @user1211 I looked at python scheduler. It is not what I am looking for. The problem is my script will only run if change my systems clock before Mar 2017.